# Can ReSharper properly parse SharePoint layouts?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, resharper, master-pages, page-layout

I am creating a SharePoint 2010 feature in Visual Studio 2010.

While ReSharper is a valuable tool for writing code, it reports lots of errors (all server-relative image references, master page reference, `ContentPlaceHolderID`'s referring to the master page and so on) in `.aspx` layout definitions. I had to exclude the master page from ReSharper completely, as it was hanging the VS process - however, the errors were reported before as well.

Is there a 'clever' way of configuring it to correctly parse those files?

Comment: Nope. R# has never worked with SharePoint layouts or controls, 2007 or 2010.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the post. I'll try to reproduce this strange behavior ASAP and ll let you know about results.

Comment: Hi. You're welcome to try out our internal ReSharper 7.0 EAP build with SharePoint support from http://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/ReSharperSetup.7.0.47.83.msi. Any feedback will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, R# has offers no support for SharePoint Application- and MasterPages. The issue is because SharePoint is using an other approach to reference assembies and because of the SharePoint specific implementation of the ASP.NET virtual path provider. So R# isn't able to locate all the required dependencies which are required to render an entire SharePoint site.

JetBrains will have to reproduce the SharePoint Designer behavior.

Thorsten

Comment: I might upvote your answer if you stick to the facts and remove "I don't think that will happen".

Comment: ReSharper 7 (http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/07/resharper-7-whats-inside/) understands SharePoint-specific master pages, resources, style sheets and JavaScript files.

Answer (score 0):

[ReSharper 7](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/07/resharper-7-whats-inside/) ([still in beta](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/07/get-resharper-70-beta/)) supports SharePoint now. ReSharper 7 understands SharePoint-specific master pages, resources, style sheets and JavaScript files.